# Как совместить showinfo и Entry в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось всплывающее окно, где должен быть лейбл(введите id) и ниже поле entry. Как я могу это сделать, если showinfo и Entry не совмещаются?

```
w = Tk()
..
showinfo(title="title", message="Введите ID", Entry(..))
```

Данный код, к сожалению, не работает

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Создайте полностью свое диалоговое окно вместо showinfo и добавляйте туда все что вам нужно. Диалоговые окна создаются через класс Toplevel.